# DataTables Editor - Field.Options.Where syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

My project tracking system needs a bit of work. Currently, every user can assign themselves a bunch of projects and track their hours on said projects.

I'm trying to add a where condition to my list of options where people can add their hours. Currently, people can select all projects. That can be a bit tiresome with lots of projects, so I want a `Where` statement to limit their options to their own projects.

Here's the problematic piece of code:

```
    .Field(new Field("ProjectEntry.IdProject")
        .Options(new Options()
            .Table("View_User_Project")
            .Value("IdProject")
            .Label("Name")
            .Where("View_User_Project", "View_User_Project.IdUser", "=", idUser) // TODO Find out what's going on
        )
        .Validator(Validation.NotEmpty())
    )
```

This "Where" method only takes one argument, an `Action<Query>` kind of argument. I've never seen an example for a `Where` statement with that kind of syntax.

Could someone provide me with an example?

---

Full DB code:

```
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var idUser = Utility.GetIdUser(context);
    var request = context.Request;

    using (var db = Utility.GetDb())
    {
        var editor = new Editor(db, "ProjectEntry", "IdProjectEntry")
            .Model<ProjectEntryModel>("ProjectEntry")
            .Model<ProjectModel>("Project")
            .Field(new Field("ProjectEntry.IdProject")
                .Options(new Options()
                    .Table("View_User_Project")
                    .Value("IdProject")
                    .Label("Name")
                    .Where("View_User_Project", "View_User_Project.IdUser", "=", idUser) // TODO Find out what's going on
                )
                .Validator(Validation.NotEmpty())
            )
            .Field(new Field("ProjectEntry.IdUser"))
            .Field(new Field("ProjectEntry.TimeWorked")
                .Validator(Validation.NotEmpty())
                .Validator(Validation.Numeric())
            )
            .Field(new Field("ProjectEntry.TimestampWeek")
                .Validator(Validation.NotEmpty())
            )
            .LeftJoin("Project", "Project.IdProject", "=", "ProjectEntry.IdProject")
            .Where("ProjectEntry.IdUser", idUser, "=");
        editor.PreCreate += (sender, e) => editor.Field("ProjectEntry.IdUser").SetValue(idUser);
        var response = editor.Process(request).Data();

        return Json(response);
    }
```

[A forum post that gave me a little bit of insight](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27856/editor-net-field-options-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was short. Turns out you need an anonymous function to edit the query object.

Example:

```
    .Field(new Field("UserProject.IdProject")
        .Options(new Options()
            .Table("View_User_Project")
            .Value("IdProject")
            .Label("Name")
            .Where((q) =>
                {
                    q.Where("View_User_Project.IdUser", idUser);
                }
            )
        )
        .Validator(Validation.NotEmpty())
    )
```